# Invoking perl from nginx

Tags: docker, perl, nginx

I have an nginx block like this where I want to run a perl script on a hello/world request. The whole set up is inside docker.

My nginx.conf:

```
http {
   perl_modules perl/lib;
   server {
      listen 80;

      location /hello/world {
          perl rewrite.pl;
      }
}
```

My docker-compose has this:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:perl
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./rewrite.pl:/etc/nginx/rewrite.pl
```

Yet when I make a request to /hello/world I get a 500 error in nginx with the following:
**call_sv("rewrite.pl") failed: "Undefined subroutine &main::rewrite.pl called."**

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html#perl). It requires a Perl expression, not a file name.

In fact, I suspect that executing a file (which could be done using `do`) would be bad, since I suspect it would pollute a namespace that's reused.

You should move your code into a module, then you use use `MyModule::mysub` in the config file to call `mysub` of the module.

(Remember, a module needs to have the `.pm` extension, and it must have a `package` directive that matches its file name.)